# Outer join two tables with null values

Tags: c#, linq, outer-join

I have this data structure:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

class Pet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Link
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public int PetId { get; set; }
}
```

and this data:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person {FirstName = "Foo"},
    new Person {FirstName = "Bar"}
};
List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet>
{
    new Pet {Id = 1, Name = "FooBoy"},
};
List<Link> links = new List<Link>
{
    new Link {Person = people.First(), PetId = pets.First().Id}
};
```

Now i want to get the list of all people and their pet names(or null, if there is no pet)
The result should be

```
Foo - FooBoy
Bar - null
```

I tried

```
var query = from person in people
    join lnk in links on person equals lnk.Person into linkPets
    from link in linkPets.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join p in pets on link.PetId equals p.Id into subPets
    from subPet in subPets.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subPet == null ? String.Empty : subPet.Name) };
```

But i get null reference exception on `link.Pet`. If i remove `linkPets.DefaultIfEmpty()`, i get only the first person.

Comment: If there's a pet with no owner, do you need *that* too?

Comment: No, i don't need pets with no owners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Before the question changed**

(Originally the link table had a reference to the pet, not an ID.)

It looks to me like you only need one join, because you can just use the `Pet` property from the link, where there is one:

```
var query = from person in people
            join lnk in links on person equals lnk.Person into linkPets
            from link in linkPets.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { person.FirstName,
                         PetName = link == null ? "" : link.Pet.Name };
```

**After the question changed**

I've left the original solution above because it's easy to transform the modified question into the original one - just do a join between `pets` and `links` first:

```
var fullLinks = from link in links
                join pet in pets on link.PetId equals pet.Id
                select new { link.Person, Pet = pet };

var query = from person in people
    join lnk in fullLinks on person equals lnk.Person into linkPets
    from link in linkPets.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { person.FirstName,
                 PetName = link == null ? "" : link.Pet.Name };
```

You could do it in a single statement if you want to, but I wouldn't:

```
var query = from person in people
    join lnk in (from link in links
                 join pet in pets on link.PetId equals pet.Id
                 select new { link.Person, Pet = pet } )
      on person equals lnk.Person into linkPets
    from link in linkPets.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { person.FirstName,
                 PetName = link == null ? "" : link.Pet.Name };
```

Comment: I think I oversimplified my task and you found an easy solution. I updated the question. The main thing: i don't actually have a Pet object in Link. I only have an Id.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get both person and pet with the link table you can do something like this:

```
var result= (
        from person in people
        from lnk in links
            .Where (w =>w.Person==person).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from p in pets
            .Where (w =>w==(lnk==null?null:lnk.Pet)).DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (p == null ? String.Empty : p.Name) }
    ).Dump();
```

Answer (score 1):

another solution is using    linkPets.DefaultIfEmpty(new Link()) (may only work with joining in memory, because your original joining works with Database)

```
 var query = from person in people
                   join lnk in links on person equals lnk.Person into linkPets
                   from link in linkPets.DefaultIfEmpty(new Link())
                   join p in pets on link.PetId equals p.Id into subPets
                   from subPet in subPets.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subPet == null ? String.Empty : subPet.Name) };
```